# how to set validation in contact form

Tags: php, validation, contacts, contact-form

how to set validation in contact from
suppose if user submit empty field then how to show Invalid input 
now email address only invalid input show i want to fix all field validation please help me how can i do this 
thanks in advance

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    function spamcheck($field) {
      // Sanitize e-mail address
      $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      // Validate e-mail address
      if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return TRUE;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    ?>


   <h2>Form</h2>
    <?php
    // display form if user has not clicked submit
    if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
      From: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
      Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
      </form>
      <?php 
    } else {  // the user has submitted the form
      // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
      if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
        // Check if "from" email address is valid
        $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["email"]);
        if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
          echo "Invalid input";
        } else {
          $email = $_POST["email"]; // sender
          $subject = $_POST["subject"];
          $message = $_POST["message"];
          // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
          $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
          // send mail
          mail("demo@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $email\n");
          echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these

```
 From: <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
 Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" required><br>
 Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message" required></textarea><br>
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-form-validation.php) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_form_validation.asp)